# Validation-combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following module:

[image]

Which accepts 2 inputs, and sorts the output in the described way.

Now, given this module, I want to design a new module which sorts 4 inputs, and Im going to do it as the following:

[image]

And I want to know what is the minimum number of input sequences I have to use in order to know for sure that the second module is working fine, given that I know that the first module is valid.

What I have noticed is that the order of 2 inputs in the entrance of the one of the two simple modules does not matter, and so the answer would not be 4!. But Im not sure how to calculate the correct minimal number.
Basically, I think the question boils down to "in how many ways can I enter a rearrngement of the sequence 1,2,3,4 in a way that the order in between A,B does not matter and the order between C,D does not matter", but if it not the case (maybe its more complicated than that and I can see it) please enlight me.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [the Wikipedia article on sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Optimal_sorting_networks), your construction for sorting four inputs using five gates is optimal.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I am not asking about the implementation - I am asking about validation of the output. I want to know the minimal input sequences I have to try in order to know for sure that the module is valid

Comment: Well, according to the same wiki article, the zero-one principle says you can validate an $n$-input sorting network by testing all $2^n$ inputs which are made of zeroes and ones. But I do not know if that is optimal.